# Prove that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1-e^x)^n\Big\rvert_{x=0}=(-1)^nn!$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, exponential-function, factorial

I'm not sure where to start with this. I have tried induction but I'm stuck on the inductive step. Could anyone let me know how to do this or give me a hint on how to approach this question?

I need to prove that the N'th derivative of $(1-e^x)^n=n!(-1)^n$ when evaluated at $x=0$

Comment: Hey Cand , think the binomial theorem looks useful here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the Maclaurin series:
$$1-e^x=-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\cdots.$$
Therefore
$$(1-e^x)^n=(-x)^n+\text{higher terms}.$$
Now differentiate $n$ times.

Comment: Please check  LHS should ne $(1-e^x)^n$.

Comment: Cool answer. I see that the reason you want the series about $x = 0$ is so that higher terms get evaluated to $0$, when you substitute $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1-e^x)^n&=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}[-ne^x(1-e^x)^{n-1}]\\
&=\frac{d^{n-2}}{dx^{n-2}}[(-1)\cdot(-1)n(n-1)e^{2x}(1-e^x)^{n-2}+\cdots]\\
&\vdots\\
&=\frac{d^{n-(n-1)}}{dx^{n-(n-1)}}[(-1)^{n-1}n(n-1)\cdots (2)e^{(n-1)x}(1-e^x)+\cdots]\\
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1-e^x)^n\Bigg\rvert_{x=0}&=\left[(-1)^{n}n!e^{nx}+\underbrace{\cdots}_{\text{Terms having powers of }(1-e^x)}\right]\Bigg\rvert_{x=0}=(-1)^nn!
\end{align*}